# Rails and Font Awesome not working? Icons not displaying

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I have added the links to Bootstrap and Font Awesome in my -Head- in App Layout but the FA icons are not displaying. They show in the DOM, but as blank items. I've tried everything, what could it be?

```
 <head>
    <title>RailsTaskManager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css Tasks:/font-awesome.min.css“>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
```

Index.html.erb, icon in -ul-

```
<ul>

  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="completed?" name="completed?" <%= task.completed ? "checked" : "" %>>
    <%= link_to("#{task.title}", "/tasks/#{task.id}") %>
    <!-- delete -->
    <%= link_to task_path(task),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do  %>
      <!-- not displaying -->
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">Delete this task</i>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <% end %>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workable example of how I've used it in my projects

```
<%= link_to "http://www.link.com/" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
<% end %>
```

Have you tried adding this to your Gemfile?

```
gem "font-awesome-rails"
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

In your application.css, include the css file:

```
/*
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

Then restart your webserver if it was previously running.

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) and some [helpers](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers) that might be helpful.

Let me know if you have any questions.